# Set and Change Resource Bundle with Afterburner.fx

Tags: java, javafx, resourcebundle

I am trying to create a multilanguage software in JavaFX using Afterburner.fx (https://github.com/AdamBien/afterburner.fx/). I can't understand if there is a way to set or to inject the resource bundle used by an Afterburner view, nor if there is a way to have different resource bundle to different views and changing the resource bundle at runtime.

In plain javafx it's possible to set a Resource Bundle for a fxml view like showed in the example below, but how to do this with afterburner?

```
private void loadView(Locale locale) {
try {
  FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();

  // Here, just the resource bundles name is mentioned. You can add support for more languages
  // by adding more properties-files with language-specific endings like
  // "E_13_Internationalization_fr.properties".
  fxmlLoader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("E_13_Internationalization", locale));

  Pane pane = (BorderPane) fxmlLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("/E_13_Internationalization.fxml").openStream());
  borderPane.setCenter(pane);
} catch (IOException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

To load a `ResourceBundle` afterburner.fx builds a bundleName from the packagename + name of your view class e.g. :

```
packagename.ExampleView -> packagename.example //('View' at the ending gets removed)
packagename.ExampleApp -> packagename.exampleapp
```

which is used for `ResourceBundle.getBundle(name)`.

Following that convention you have to create a separate resourceBundle for each of your views, and place it in the corresponding view package.

If you want to use a different naming pattern, or a single resourceBundle for all of your views, you can set the resourceBundle before calling `exampleView.getView()`, which will then initialize the `FMXLLoader`with the updated resourceBundle.

```
public abstract class BaseView extends FXMLView {

    public static final ResourceBundle RESOURCE_BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundleName");

    public BaseView() {
        this.bundle = RESOURCE_BUNDLE;
    }

    public BaseView(ResourceBundle bundle) {
        this.bundle = bundle;
    }

}
```

https://github.com/AdamBien/afterburner.fx/blob/master/src/main/java/com/airhacks/afterburner/views/FXMLView.java